# how I can determine which button was triggered by the enter input, or how I can identify which button is the default on the window

Tags: python, winapi, button, hook, message-queue

I'm using Python (PyHook3 package) to write a plug-in that recognizes some message boxes (implemented using Delphi Application.MessageBox) and determines the operator's actions, mainly to identify what keys were clicked.I used a hook to recognize mouse and keyboard input. Now I can recognize the handle of the button when I click the mouse button, **but only the handle of the dialog window when I hit enter (the input cannot recognize the specific button). And these Windows have different default buttons. I can't tell which one is the default button.**

1)I've used both 'Win32GUi.peekMessage' and 'Win32gui.PeekMessage' to try to intercept messages, but it didn't work.

2)I've used win32gui.WindowFromPoint(win32gui.GetCursorPos()), but it didn't work.

3)I also tried to figure out a way to verify the default button, but couldn't.

**I want to know how I can determine which button was triggered by the enter input, or how I can identify which button is the default on the window.**

Looking forward to getting your answers!Thank you so much!

The Delphi code of message boxes(Dialog) like this
(It's actually a normal Windows message box, but with different default buttons and can be implemented in other languages):

```
    Application.MessageBox('The file already exists. Overwrite it?', 'Hint', MB_YESNO)
    
    Application.MessageBox('The file already exists. Overwrite it?', 'Hint', MB_YESNO + MB_ICONQUESTION)
    
    Application.MessageBox('The file already exists. Overwrite it?', 'Hint', MB_YESNO + MB_ICONQUESTION + MB_DEFBUTTON2)
```

The message boxes looks like this:

[Default 'No' Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Pkh.png)

[Default 'Yes' Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyuNC.png)

Part of the code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
#Python version:3.5.4
#  #
from win32 import win32process
import time
import threading
#import win32
import psutil
import PyHook3 as pyHook
import pythoncom
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api
import datetime as dt
Operator = ""    
TAPID = 0        
TopWindowHWND=0  
TopFormName = ""
TopWindowPID = 0
MainThreadID = 0

LastHintHWND = 0
HintText = ""   

state = 0
def OnMouseEvent(event):
    # if LastHintHWND==0:
    #     return True
    EventHWND = event.Window
    EventTime = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')[0:17]#event.Time
    print("MouseEvent="+win32gui.GetWindowText(EventHWND),"EventTime = ",EventTime)
    EventWindowName=event.WindowName

    if event.Message==513:
        print('Time:', event.Time) 
        if event.WindowName != None:
            Operate=event.MessageName + event.WindowName+"\n"
        else:
            Operate=event.MessageName + "\n"
        print(EventHWND,EventTime,Operate)
    return True
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print('MessageName:',event.MessageName)          
    print('Message:',event.Message)
    print('Time:',event.Time)
    print('Window:',event.Window)
    print('WindowName:',event.WindowName)
    print('Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii))   
    print('Key:', event.Key)                         
    print('KeyID:', event.KeyID)                   
    print('ScanCode:', event.ScanCode)           
    print('Extended:', event.Extended)         
    print('Injected:', event.Injected)
    print('Alt', event.Alt)                     
    print('Transition', event.Transition)     

    if str(event.Key)=='F12':   
        win32api.PostQuitMessage(0)
    return True

def GetProcessIdByHWND(HWND):
    thread_id = 0
    process_id = 0
    app = ""
    if HWND!=0:
        app = win32gui.GetWindowText(HWND)
        thread_id, process_id = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND)
        process = psutil.Process(process_id)
    else:
        pass
    return app,process_id

def WindowTraversal():
    global TAPID,state,LastHintHWND,HintText
    TAFormName = ""
    while 1:
        #TfrmMain is the fram class of program
        TopMianFormHWND = win32gui.FindWindow('TfrmMain',None)
        TopMianForm,TAPID = GetProcessIdByHWND(TopMianFormHWND)
        if TopMianForm.find("日操作流程")>=0:
           #do something
           pass
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start capture...')
    MainThreadID=threading.currentThread().ident
    try:
        ThreadWT = threading.Thread(target=WindowTraversal,name='ThreadWT',args=())
        ThreadWT.setDaemon(True)
        # threads.append(ThreadWT)
        ThreadWT.start()
    except:
        print("Error:--")
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    hm.MouseAllButtons = OnMouseEvent
    hm.HookMouse()
    hm.KeyAll = OnKeyboardEvent
    hm.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages(10000)
    while 1:
        open_str = input("whether restart(anykey): \n")
        if state == 2 or open_str=='1':
            pythoncom.PumpMessages(10000)
        pass
```

Comment: You have set yourself up to solve a hard problem by choosing the wrong approach. Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) and [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) instead, and you won't have to deal with low-level input details like retroactively mapping ambiguous keyboard input to an unambiguous action.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem through your code. It seems that there are some errors in the hook mouse in the code. I suggest you provide it if possible. Of course, I think it is difficult to get a certain button pressed in other forms through hooks.

Comment: UI Automation and WinEvents seems to be the solution to my problem, so I first looked at the link you gave me, then consulted the PyWin32 manual and looked at some functions such as:
'win32gui.GetClassLong','win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents','win32event.MsgWaitForMultipleObjects','win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects'
I tried a few things, but either the syntax was wrong or I still couldn't get the event message.
Then I went to 'Python35\Lib\site-packages\win32\Demos' but couldn't find a demo that did what I wanted.
So can you give me a small demo program, thank you very much!@IInspectable

Comment: I deleted the necessary code by mistake, and now I have corrected it. Since I cannot provide the identification program, I have given a few statements to implement the message box in Delphi, of course, you can also use other languages to simply write a message box to test.Thank you very much! @ZhuSong

Comment: I think the reason for the difference between the mouse and the keyboard is the difference in pyhook's own implementation, so it cannot be distinguished in this way. You can try to use `WinEvents` and use [GetGUIThreadInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getguithreadinfo) to retrieve the corresponding event form.